# How to add custom vallidator for Node.js / app.patch method findByIdAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

this question about backend development node.js how do i update a database data by using object id
please help me to learn those things custom validator

```
app.patch("/users/:id", async (req, res) => {
  

  try {
    const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
      runValidators: true,
      new: true,
    });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }
    res.send(user);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send()
  }
});
```

this my code please modify to add validators like allowedUpdates ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongoose ObjectId validator:

```
mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)
```

Update your code to look like this:

```
// require mongoose or import it
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

app.patch("/users/:id", async (req, res) => {
   if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, 
         (error, docs) => {
            if (error) {
               // return "error" response
               return res.status(500).json({
                  status: 500,
                  message: error
               })
            } else {
               // return "success" response
               return res.status(200).json({
                  status: 200,
                  message: 'user successfully updated',
                  data: docs
               })
            }
         })
   } else {
      // return "bad request" response
      return res.status(400).json({
         status: 400,
         message: 'bad request'
      })
   }
})
```

I removed the try-catch block because it really isn't necessary with this update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
app.patch("/users/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const allowedUpdates = [ // Define the fields you want to allow for update];

  const updates = Object.keys(req.body);
  const isValidOperation = updates.every((update) =>
    allowedUpdates.includes(update)
  );

  if (!isValidOperation) {
    return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Invalid updates!' });
  }

  try {
    const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
      runValidators: true,
      new: true,
    });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }

    res.send(user);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send();
  }
});
```